# Tools for generate PDF that contains graph and table

Tags: pdf, css, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

I'm looking for something for generate PDF.

PDF requirement ;

- A4 ( 21 x 29,7cm ) ( A4 ISO 216 or ISO 269 )
- Support landscape format
- Page concept ( do not print something between 2 pages )*
- Header / footer for page ...
- Support chart ( or can add chart with other libs ) ( pie, bar, column )
- Support long table ( repeat header if is on two page )
- Pdf structure not exatly same every time ( chart type, isn't same each time )

Other Requirement:

- run on linux
- can be automated on server
- can load 'dynamique' json ( json structure use date as key ... json doens't support null, so sometime some key is missing ... )
- rework on the data ... data can't be used directly for making the report.
- can be maintained by a web-develloper
- easy scalable

The project start with `wkhtmltopdf` and have rapidly migrate to `Puppeteer` but the page concept is missing (or preview dev didn't find how to do), some difficulty with chart js libs ...

Actualy the project use FastReport.net (throught WineHQ for getting chart ). But its hard to maintain / edit for our dev...  running .net over linux under WineHQ its not ideal ... ), play with chart legends is realy hard ... ( juste moving or deal with long legends )

Comment: Hello Andrelec.  What other constraints do you have?  Eg. programming language, cloud / own-server etc?

Comment: We have a dedicated server running on Debian, so that need to run on it... I didn't have a big constraints over language ( js / php... Something that I can learn fast...). I already try jsreport, but the concept of page is not full implemented, need custom css for header /footer...